# graphql server side validation

Tags: validation, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I just want to get a gauge of what people think is the best practice for doing validation of user input fileds (such as url or email address) on the server with a graphql / orm setup.

My application is using apollo server / gql and sequelize as the orm.

I've seen some who do validation on the model in sequelize and other examples of validation in the graphql resolver with with a validation library or using custom scalars.

Is any one way preferable? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input validation is some kind of [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), like authentication and authorization. From my knowledge, there are five ways can do this.

- Validation in resolver with the general approach, e.g. `if (validationPass) {...} else {..}` - Too verbose, keep the resolver thin is a best practice. Because It's some kind of route layer. Not recommend
- Validation in resolver using a composition library, e.g. [graphql-resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/#graphql-resolvers) - Recommend
- Validation in the model layer (ORM) using some decorators or model schema definition. - This is the traditional effective way no matter you use GraphQL, gRPC, soap WSDL, RESTful API. From the classic MVC software development idea. Recommend
- Validation in GraphQL schema directive - A little complex, not recommend
- Validation in GraphQL [middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-middleware) - A little complex, you need to design the middleware and map the validation rules to the corresponding Query and Mutation, you quite possibly need to use the `info` parameter to get the GraphQL operation. Not recommend

Comment: thanks for the overview. i ended up doing it in the model layer since it was already supported by Sequelize.